# Histogram Bar Line Thickness

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, histograms, charts, plot-themes

This feels like it should be pretty simple but I am struggling. Does anyone know how to control the thickness of the lines of the bar in a histogram?

I tried playing with `ChartStyle` and `BaseStyle` but nothing seems to manipulate the line thickness of the bars.

Cheers!

EDIT:

```
Histogram[
{Table[n/n 0.0, {n, 1, 400}], Table[n/n 0.2, {n, 1, 137}], 
Table[n/n 0.4, {n, 1, 45}], Table[n/n 0.6, {n, 1, 13}], 
Table[n/n 0.8, {n, 1, 3}], Table[n/n 1.0, {n, 1, 1}], 
Table[n/n 1.2, {n, 1, 1}]},
ChartStyle -> White,
Evaluate[PlotStyles],
BaseStyle -> Thickness[0.0025],
ImagePadding -> {{60, 60}, {50, 5}}
];
```

Comment: Can you includes some code to showcase your problem?

Comment: @MarcoB I have added my code.

Comment: @QuantumPenguin - in your code `PlotStyles` doesn't evaluate to anything.  Regardless, the answers below should be able to help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 2:**  Based on the accepted answer it now seems that removing the bottom of edge of rectangles is not essential. In that case, the option `ChartBaseStyle` gives the desired result (there is no need for custom `ChartElementFunction`s):

```
Histogram[data, ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Thickness[.01]]]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[data, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
 ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Opacity[1, Red], Thickness[.01]}]]
```

[image]

**Update:** The `ChartElementFunction` in the original post works only for the default setting for the option `BarOrigin`. The new function `ceF2` works for arbitrary values for the `BarOrigin` option.

```
ceF2[cedf_: "GlassRectangle", o : OptionsPattern[]][col_: Black, thickness_: 3] := 
 Module[{or = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BarOrigin"], ll = Tuples[#][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]]},
   ll = RotateRight[ll, Switch[or, Bottom, 0, Top, 2, Left, 3, Right, 1]] ;
   {ChartElementDataFunction[cedf, o][##], 
    col, AbsoluteThickness[thickness], CapForm["Butt"], Line[ll]}] &
```

Examples:

```
Grid[Partition[Histogram[data, ChartStyle -> 1, ImageSize -> 300, 
     PlotLabel -> Style["BarOrigin -> " <> ToString[#], 16, "Panel"], 
     ChartElementFunction -> ceF2["FadingRectangle", "GradientOrigin" -> Top][
       Dynamic[Darker@CurrentValue["Color"]], 5], 
     BarOrigin -> #] & /@ {Bottom, Top, Left, Right}, 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

A more flexible chart element function that modifies built-in chart element functions to add thick lines:

```
ClearAll[ceF]
ceF[cedf_: "GlassRectangle", o : OptionsPattern[]][col_: Black, thickness_: 3] := 
  {ChartElementDataFunction[cedf, o][##], 
   col, AbsoluteThickness[thickness], CapForm["Butt"],
   Line[Tuples[#][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]]]} &
```

Examples:

```
SeedRandom[42];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];

Histogram[data, ChartStyle -> 1, ChartElementFunction -> ceF[][]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Histogram[data, ChartStyle -> 1, 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  ceF["FadingRectangle"][Dynamic[Darker@Darker@CurrentValue["Color"]], 5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Histogram[data, ChartStyle -> 1, 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  ceF["FadingRectangle", "GradientOrigin"->Top][Dynamic[Darker@CurrentValue["Color"]], 5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Histogram[data, 5, ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Cyan, Purple}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  ceF["FadingRectangle", "GradientOrigin"->Top][Dynamic[Darker@CurrentValue["Color"]], 5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can remove parts of lines under the axis by adding `CapForm["Butt"]`.

Comment: Thank you @AlexeyPopkov; good point. Updated with your suggestion.

Comment: @kglr very, very nice. I'll give you the accepted answer as it is very detailed and solves all of my problems.

Comment: @QuantumPenguin, please see Update 2.

Answer (score 8):

The most direct and versatile way would be to generate your own chart elements. Fortunately, for rectangles this is quite easy:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 100}, 1000];

Clear[thick]
thick[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, values_, metadata_] := 
   {EdgeForm[Thick], Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]}

Histogram[data, ChartElementFunction -> thick]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Once you decide to make your own primitives, you also gain some flexibility, e.g. by choosing to leave off the bottom edge of each bar, as requested in comments:

```
Clear[thickNoBottom]
thickNoBottom[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, values_, metadata_] := {
  {EdgeForm[None], Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]},
  {Thickness[0.015], Black, CapForm["Butt"],
   Line[{{xmin, ymin}, {xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmax, ymin}}]}
}

Histogram[data, ChartBaseStyle -> Thick, ChartElementFunction -> thickNoBottom]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @MacroB Nice, I am surprised that there isn't an inbuilt feature for this!

Comment: Although, I don't suppose you know how to remove the thickness on the lines where the bar meets the x-axis...

Comment: @QuantumPenguin Yes something can be done once you decide to make your own primitives. See edit.

Comment: You can remove parts of lines under the axis by adding `CapForm["Butt"]`.

Comment: @Alexey Thank you for the suggestion: those were in fact bothering me a little! I'll update the answer as soon as I get back to a computer.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking to modify the `EdgeForm` of your `ChartStyle`, and this is shown in the documentation for [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html), in the `Options` section.

```
SeedRandom[42];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
Histogram[data, 
 ChartStyle -> {EdgeForm[
    Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Black, Opacity[1]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: B, Also a great answer! I prefer this as it seems to be simpler. Do you know how to remove the edges on the bottom lines that join to the x axis or mask it somehow?